# full text search in jena sparql?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena

I am new to sparql and I am trying to search a word in one of the property . The simple queries works fine but I don't know how to perform full text search . I saw this example on jena website :

```
    PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?s
{ ?s text:query (rdfs:label 'word' 10) ; 
     rdfs:label ?label 
}
```

my model contains property named **SUB:** and I want to write a query for that . I don't understand what is text and query in text:query means in the above example . Pardon me if this question doesn't meet the requirements of SO.
Link to website:http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need a full text index:

```
SELECT ?s
{ ?s your:property ?o .
  FILTER regex(str(?o), "word", "i")
}
```

but if you do `text:query` is a "property function" -- it trigger accessing the Apache Lucene index and causing `?s` to be bound to each of the answers from a match of `'word'` (to a limit of 10) over the `rdfs:label` properties if you have correctly configured and loaded the data and index.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I check a date range using Filters if my date is of the form Fri May 23 10:20:13 IST 2014

Comment: @user3654540 That's a different question that should be asked a different question.  Part of what makes Stack Overflow useful is the ability to find questions and their answers.  People won't look for the answers to that question here, or the answer for this question there.  Please ask it as a new question.